# Timestamp Difference - Syntax Error - Condtitional Selects

Tags: mysql, optimization, syntax

Here is what I have right now

```
SELECT name, admin, reason, unban,
FROM_UNIXTIME(date) AS datetime, HOUR(difference) AS HRemain,
MINUTE(difference) AS MRemain
FROM (SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, unban, NOW()))) AS difference FROM banned, banned) 
WHERE name = '%e'
```

I get some syntax error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, unban, NOW()))) AS difference FROM banned, banned) WH' at line 3
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve.

### Table banned

```
name   | admin     | reason | unban(TIMESTAMP) | date
Yashas | SomeAdmin | test   | 180              | 60
```

Required Results:

```
Player who was banned: Yashas (given)
Administrator who banned: SomeAdmin (need to fetch from the db)
Banned on: January 1st, 1971 (must be obtained from date) (Need the string as datetime) (I decided that I don't need the time, just the date as a string)
Unban Time left: 0 Hours 2 Minutes (I need the hours left as HRemain and minutes left as MRemain)
```

I need the following:

- unban as a date-time string
- time remaining for unban from current time. I need just hours and minutes remaining.
- and rest of the content of the table as it is including unban

If possible optimize the query for the following:
If unban is set to 0 then it means its a permanent ban and therefore I don't need the time remaining until unban. So in every case where unban is zero, I don't need HRemain, MRemain.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE `banned` (
`name` varchar(21) NOT NULL,
`admin` varchar(21) NOT NULL,
`reason` varchar(81) NOT NULL,
`unban` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My old query which was working but isn't efficient.

```
SELECT name, admin, reason, unban, FROM_UNIXTIME(date) AS datetime, 
HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, unban, NOW())))) AS HRemain, 
MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, unban, NOW())))) AS MRemain 
FROM banned WHERE name = '%e'
```

Comment: EDIT:will add it to the Q

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66a53/2

Comment: And the sample data and desired result?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Had a power cut. Added sample date and desired result.

Comment: Can you give me the new URL.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47f13 - Edited the fiddle

Comment: Perhaps you meant `name LIKE '%e'` instead of `name = '%e'`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, admin, reason, unban, FROM_UNIXTIME(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS datetime, 
HOUR(x.difference) AS HRemain, MINUTE(x.difference) AS MRemain 
FROM(SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, unban, NOW()))) AS difference FROM banned) AS x, banned 
WHERE name LIKE 'Yashas'
```

Solved it myself. Just had to get a textbook and study.

EDIT: Server returns datetime as NULL for some reason.

Comment: Your SQLFiddle won't work with the SQL as written.

Comment: datetime is always returned as NULL and HRemain and MRemain are not set to correct values.